# This page isn't available despite having access

Tags: confluence

In one of our Confluence [team spaces](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/spaces-139459.html), we are consistently experiencing the problem of content not rendering (despite us having access to space)

[image]

More specifically, symptoms are as follows

- Most other spaces work just fine; thus far we've find the problem to be isolated to just **one particular space**
- Within the affected space, **some pages still render fine**. But majority show this message

---

One thing to point out, we've found this impacted space to take *slightly longer than usual to load on browser* (longer than what other spaces take, that is)

Hereby re-iterating that we've checked that **users have proper accesses** (read / edit) to the space

---

What we've tried

- Log out of Confluence and log back in
- [Clear cookies](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en) for [confluence.altassian.com](https://confluence.altassian.com)

---

What could be wrong here?

---

**UPDATE-1**

So the other day, we discovered this strange hack that worked

- Open Confluence on [Incognito Window](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)
- *(and then of course log in)*

That's it! This fixes the problem

But it is hardly ideal since we have to persistently keep an Incognito Window running for this sole purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ad-blocker to blame*

---

Failed experimentation with clearing cookies made me forget another fundamental difference of Chrome's Incognito mode (vs normal window)

> By default, all extensions are disabled on incognito (unless [explicitly enabled](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/3194459?hl=en&msgid=3194680) by user)

Just [whitelisting](https://help.getadblock.com/support/solutions/articles/6000055743-whitelist-pages-to-disable-adblock-on-specific-sites) `my_org.confluence.net` on [AdBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-%E2%80%94-best-ad-blocker/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom) resolved the issue

[image]

---

The [support pages](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb) do mention some issues with adblockers

- [Some images not displaying, endlessly loading on Confluence page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/some-images-not-displaying-endlessly-loading-on-confluence-page-911935177.html)
- [Unable to Create New User Accounts on Browsers with Ad Blocking or Password Filling Extensions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloudkb/unable-to-create-new-user-accounts-on-browsers-with-ad-blocking-or-password-filling-extensions-720405890.html)

---

Credits to [@GautamSahni](https://www.linkedin.com/in/gautam-sahni/) for this finding